# Why is cloning TFS root branches recommended?

Tags: git, version-control, tfs, git-tfs

The `git-tfs` tool allows you to clone TFS branches to Git repositories.  One way of displaying the available TFS branches is to use the `git-tfs list-remote-branches` command, which (at the end) states: "Cloning root branches (marked by [*]) is recommended!"

Simply put, why?  I don't see any particular benefit in cloning root branches... what if you want to clone a child branch?  What's so good about root branches?

Comment: where are you reading this information?  Could you post the URL or literal text of the message?

Comment: Here's the [source code](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/blob/master/GitTfs/Commands/ListRemoteBranches.cs#L61) for the command.

Comment: Only a guess, but perhaps it just wants to call out the fact unless you're cloning trunk you may be cloning a feature branch, or something that is intended as someone's "play area" rather than trunk.  If cloning something from github, I would more often be cloning the main branch/stable branch/trunk over a dev/feature branch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I think I figured out the answer to my own question.

If you clone a root branch, `git-tfs` clones all the child branches too (which is why root branches are preferred) - however, *it doesn't initialize them* in the git repository by default!  You must specify the `--with-branches` parameter to get it to do this.  Then, you will see the root branch and all its child branches initialized after checkout when you do a `git branch` command.